# Driver Install fails with: successfully added <driver>.inf and installed on 0 device(s)

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, drivers, installation

**Context**

I had to wipe my device and install a clean version of windows 11.

I am attempting to install my Wireless network drivers - the installer asserts that it has executed successfully but no drivers appear in device manager, even after restarting the device.

The driver that I am installing is [this one](https://www.asus.com/us/SupportOnly/ROG%20Zephyrus%20G14/HelpDesk_Download/).

**I have tested 3 different installation methods:**

- Installation with a .exe with a Wizard
- Extracting the driver contents and doing the install with the included batch file
- Installing from the device manager 'Add Driver' button

None have worked successfully for the network drivers. The required driver is still not showing up in the network adapters panel (sorry that it isn't a screenshot).

[image]

'Adding Driver' with device manager yields the following logs :

[image]

I want to know why the installer says that '0 devices' had the software installed instead of '1 devices'. Knowing why this discrepancy occurs will allow me to continue working out why my drivers do not install.

**Other Information**

I have tested installing other drivers and they have worked successfully.

I have attempted to install the [basic intel network drivers](https://www.intel.com.au/content/www/au/en/download/19351/windows-10-and-windows-11-wi-fi-drivers-for-intel-wireless-adapters.html) but that also has a failed install.

**System Information**

ROG Zephyrus G14 RTX 3060 (2021)

Microsoft Windows 11 Home

Version 10.0.22000 Build 22000

Comment: I do not have a solution for this specific error code, but what did end up being the solution was that I was trying to install intel WLAN drivers instead of mediatek ones. The thread I used to solve my problem is the one here: https://www.reddit.com/r/ZephyrusG14/comments/ohezpp/g14_network_adapter_missing/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was due to user error, selecting the wrong manufacturer's drivers.

Comment: yep close the question, youre correct